# Azure Resource Manager template project using Clean Architecture .Net Core Project

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I am having a problem to figure out at which project i include the **Azure Resource Manager** project. My solution follows the below design :

[image: Clean Architecture]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-web-application-architectures

So in which Project to be included :

1) Core

2) Infrastructure

3) Web

Comment: this is as opinion based as possible ;)

Comment: Choose the feature what you need in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you want to put all pipeline related operations, sdev scripts related to the solution level.

in the picture above, they are not focusing on that, it is focused on the code itself.

so I suggest having this structure instead

```
- solution.sln
|
- src/
|
- dev/
```

in the source you can put the solution in the boxes above 
in dev in can put everything related to development helper classes across projects, like pipeline scripts, scaffolding scripts .... etc

it might be also that these files points to specific file inside our project level, in case there is a specific configuration for this specific project. but for generic ones I do prefer to put them outside in the solution level

if the dev folder became complicated you can put Project.json and convert to its own project.